# &nbsp; not working with javascript if condition

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am having javascript problem in my VF page so I am posting this question here.

Here is my code

```
 <html>
 <input id="xyz" value="&nbsp;"/>
 <script>
    alert( document.getElementById('xyz').value);
    var x = document.getElementById('xyz').value;
    if(  x == '&nbsp;' )
    alert(1)
    else
    alert(2);
 </script>
</html>
```

The input field xyz is having the value as   I am checking the  value in javascript but the if condition never evaluates to true. What could be the problem?

Comment: if this is a pure javascript question, you'll have a much faster responce at our "parent site" stackoverflow. The question or issue doesn't appear to be VF related ?

Comment: Now posted on Stackoverflow: [&nbsp; not working with javascript if condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133593/nbsp-not-working-with-javascript-if-condition).

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the fact that you are comparing two string objects, which although containing identical value do not necessarily pose two instances of identical object.

E.g. contraty to usual expectations, the following JS code will result with **false**

```
var a = "some string";
var b = "some string";
alert(a == b);
```

What you should do is wrap each side of the comparison in an **[String.valueOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_string.asp)**, which will return the primitive value of the String object:

```
String.valueOf(document.getElementById('xyz').value) == String.valueOf("&nbsp;")
```

For more info on string comparison in JS and good practices in JS comparison overall, visit this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/javascript-string-equality-whats-the-correct-way